# Как в Android воспроизвести 2 звука одновременно

Tags: android, аудио

Как в Android воспроизвести 2 звука одновременно

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`android.media.SoundPool`

В конструкторе указали, сколько звуков можно проигрывать одновременно.

```
soundPool = new SoundPool(2, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
```

С помощью метода `load` загрузили нужные звуки, получили их идентификаторы.

```
soundID1 = soundPool.load(this, R.raw.sound1, 1);
soundID2 = soundPool.load(this, R.raw.sound2, 1);
```

Дождались загрузки звуков

```
soundPool.setOnLoadCompleteListener(new OnLoadCompleteListener() {
      @Override
      public void onLoadComplete(SoundPool soundPool, int sampleId,
          int status) {
        loaded += 1;
      }
    });
```

Можно проигрывать звуки:

```
if( loaded > 1 ) {
    soundPool.play(soundID1, 1f, 1f, 1, 0, 1f);
    soundPool.play(soundID2, 1f, 1f, 1, 0, 1f);
}
```